# Polymorphism - Base Class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I'm making an event-driven program that accepts customers and based on their food order, determines how long it'll take until the next customer can be served.

I'm just having trouble determining how to organize the subclasses for the food items ordered.

I made an abstract `Base Class` called `DataItem`, but it seems redundant to make a subclass for each item, i.e. `Bagel`, `Sandwich`,... when the only thing that differs between them is their name and the amount of time it takes to make it.

I've been reading about Polymorphism but it seems best to keep the `Base Classes` very generic and put the coding into their subclasses, so I'm a bit confused if I've completely misinterpreted what I've been reading, and that of course, I should make subclasses for each food item. Could anyone be so kind as to clear this up for me?

Comment: A hammer is a useful tool - but that doesn't mean that you must find some way to apply a hammer to every task. Similarly, polymorphism is a useful tool - it's just not useful for the particular problem at hand.

Comment: If it's really only about the name and the preparation time, you don't need inheritance. If it goes further in any regard where the food types matter (e.g., prepare a `Bagel` from `Bread` and `Cheese`), construct different classes and couple them via inheritance or type erasure (see my answer).

Comment: OOP is good for dynamic change of behaviour. It's not at all suited to build data structures. The relational data model is vastly superior for all data-centric problems.

Answer (score 1):

Now, this is a bit opinionated, but using subclasses rather than just having a field "name" and "preparation time" in your class only makes sense if your subclasses actually *behave* differently, or you need to do different things with them based on their type.

Don't over-OOP C++. Bjarne Stroustrup himself says that C++ isn't *purely* object-oriented.

Comment: Thank-you for your quick response! That's the thing, the subclasses don't behave differently, they just have different preparation times, but it still left me confused. Do you think that I should just read in the text file in `main` with a switch statement and say "bagel 5 minutes, sandwich 4 minutes..." and completely not use `DataItem`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any polymorphism here. They have just the same properties with different values. There is just one class, with many instances, initialized to different values.

Answer (score -2):

You could indeed use inheritance:

```
struct FoodItem
{
    using DurationType = std::chrono::seconds;

    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
    virtual DurationType timeToPrepare() const = 0;
};
```

and then derive all your food items from this class. The main thing you gain is that you can store any food item in a container -- which is what you most probably want to do.

---

The previous is the standard approach. However, as @MarcusMüller already mentioned, it is often more convenient to simply provide these functions in your food item class without inheriting from some base class. But nevertheless, you want to store the items somewhere in a container. For this, you can use **type erasure**

```
struct FoodBase
{
    using DurationType = std::chrono::seconds;

    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
    virtual DurationType timeToPrepare() const = 0;
};

template<typename FoodType>
struct Food : FoodBase
{
    virtual std::string name() const override { return food.name(); };
    virtual DurationType timeToPrepare() const override { return food.timeToPrepare() };

    Food(FoodType food) : food(std::move(food)) {}
private:
    FoodType food;
};
```

Now you can store, say, any `Bagel` and `Sandwich` as

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FoodBase> > foodVec;
foodVec.push_back(std::make_unique<Food<Bagel> >{Bagel{}});
foodVec.push_back(std::make_unique<Food<Sandwich> >{Sandwich{}});
```

It's in principle the same as the usual inheritance, but it's obtained through a class which completely stands aside he food items. You do not enforce that all food types provide all virtual functions, and this reduces the coupling.

In this way, you can outsource many different properties without having to set up a thorough inheritance hierarchy.

---

And, as a final option: if it's really only about the name and the duration, you can use one class which provides both these quantities:

```
struct Food
{
     auto name() const { return _name; }
     auto timeToPrepare() const { return _timeToPrepare; }

     //...
private:
     std::string _name;
     DurationType _timeToPrepare;
};
```

But in my experince this is often too simple for real programs.

Comment: Containers are not polymorphic respect to to the values they contains.  If you push a derived value, you slice it.

Comment: Why have a templates `Food`? Why not have a base class `Food` and just store pointers to `Bagel` and `Sandwich` etc. that are derived from it? You're just making the problem more complicated than it was originally for the sake of adding OOP.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: because the second alternative shows type erasure, which is different from the standard inheritance approach. The idea is: the derived class template can hold *any* type, as long as it provides the methods `name()`  and `timeToPrepare()`. With almost no overhead, one gets the benefits of inheritance but without having to derive everything from a common base class. With type erasure one can basically combine any types (say a `Car` and a `Dog` which both `makeNoise()`), even a posteriori if the code is already finished. I find it particularly useful in the CRTP framework.

Comment: @davidhigh where do you get the idea that this incurs "almost no overhead"? This method actually incurs more overhead than standard inheritance because it has to make one more indirect call through the object it stores rather than directly with the object. I do like the whole 'concepts' approach though: e.g. any object that implements the concept '`makeNoise()`' can be stored and called.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: the overhead I was talking of was rather meant with respect to the copy of the object. With respect to the call overhead: the compiler exactly knows what it calls. I don't know what it'll do in practice, but I see no reason why it should not inline the call to `food.name()` (--this is basically what any expression template library relies on). If so, the way until being called is the same as in normal inheritance, but the overhead is: (i) a copy with storage-by-value (ii) lifetime issues with storage-by-reference (iii) a call overhead with storage-by-shared-pointer.